# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "XXXX" (type string) at path "_id" for model "XXXXX"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have created a form that takes image url from user and stores it in MongoDB, but when I try to insert the link from the db via ejs the app crashes displaying this error " Cast to ObjectId failed for value "XXXX" (type string) at path "_id" for model "XXXXX" "
This problem appears only with the image, it works perfectly fine with anchor tags or other elements.

JavaScript

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const LandingPage = require('./models/landingpage')

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/landing-page', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});


const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Database connected");
});

app.engine('ejs', ejsMate)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index');
})
app.get('/create',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('create');
})
app.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
    const landingPage = new LandingPage(req.body.LandingPage);
    landingPage.title = req.body.title;
    landingPage.image = req.body.image;
    landingPage.aflink = req.body.aflink;
    landingPage.description = req.body.description;
    await landingPage.save();
    res.redirect(`/pages/${landingPage._id}`);
})
app.get('/pages',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('pages');
})
app.get('/pages/:id', async (req,res)=>{
    const {id} = req.params;
    const landingPage = await LandingPage.findById(id);
    res.render('landingpage',{landingPage});
})

app.listen('3000',()=>{
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
})
```

Html/ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><%=landingPage.title%></h1>
    <img src=" <%=landingPage.image%>  " alt=""> // When I remove this line the app works again
    <a href="<%=landingPage.aflink%>">Press here</a>
    <h2><%=landingPage.description%></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked values stored to DB? Next try to debug (console.log) what you've get from DB to landingPage. Next try to output all values as text, not setting them in ejs templates

Comment: Thank you for answering, I've tried that, it shows the correct strings, only when passing it to src on img element i get errors.